# SharedPreferences Base64 encoding assistance needed

Tags: android, encryption, base64, sharedpreferences

My Application which should receive a username and password from EditText fields, encrypt them using base64 and store them in sharedPreferences it not working properly. The program compiles and runs with no error but does not encrypt the data. The data is stored in clear text. Not sure where I went wrong with this code.

Code:

```
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    user=rName.getText().toString().trim();
    pass=rPwd.getText().toString().trim();

    if(arg0==regBttn){
        if((user.length()!=0))
        {
            if((pass.length()!=0))
            {

                sp=getSharedPreferences("AccessApp",MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE);
                Editor myEditor=sp.edit();

                try {
                    myEditor.putString("USERNAME_KEY", user);
                    byte[ ] superSecretKeyBytes = Base64.decode(user);
                    byte[] key = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
                    for (int i = 0; i &lt; pass.length(); i++) {
                        key[i] = superSecretKeyBytes[i];
                    }
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                try {
                    myEditor.putString("PASSWORD_KEY", pass);
                    byte[ ] superSecretKeyBytes = Base64.decode(pass);
                    byte[] key = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
                    for (int i = 0; i &lt; pass.length(); i++) {
                        key[i] = superSecretKeyBytes[i];
                    }
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                myEditor.commit();
                Toast.makeText(this, "Registration is successfull",10000).show();
                i=new Intent(this,AccessApp.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Please Enter password", 10000).show();
            }
        }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(this,"Please Enter Username",10000).show();
        }
    }

    else if(arg0==rtnBttn){
        AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Exit");
        builder.setMessage("Do you want to exit");
        builder.setCancelable(false);
        builder.setPositiveButton("Yes",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                finish();
            }
        });
        builder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                arg0.cancel();
            }
        });
        AlertDialog alert=builder.create();
        alert.show();

    }
}

public String encrypt(String toencrypt, byte key[]) throws Exception {
    SecretKeySpec secret = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secret);
    byte[] encryptedbytes = cipher.doFinal(toencrypt.getBytes());
    String encrypted = Base64.encodeBytes(encryptedbytes);
    return encrypted;

}
```

Comment: I don't see a call to your encrypt function. Is it called? Have you stepped through with a debugger?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are doing two mistakes:

1. You are calling `myEditor.putString("USERNAME_KEY", user);` before you encript the value in the string user. The same goes for password.
2. You are calling `Base64.decode()` instead of `Base64.encode()` when you want to encode the strings `user` and `pass`

Comment: Thanks for catching that. When I make the change from Base64.decode() to Base64.encode() I receive the following error  " The method encode(ByteBuffer, ByteBuffer) in the type Base64 is not applicable for the arguments (String)"

Comment: You need to convert the String to ByteBuffer. See documentation in http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Base64.html. Regards